# Android Eclipse Plugin "reset adb" gives "Adb connection Error:EOF" error, not blocking, but what is it?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to work through their notepad tutorial and it describes how the Eclipse project should automagically build and re-generate the auto-generated code when a file is saved.  That wasn't happening, and looking at their debugging, they suggest the "reset adb" link in the DDMS perspective in the Devices panel.  When I try to do that, I get the following output which I assume is bad:

```
[2010-01-03 23:09:51 - DeviceMonitor]Adb connection Error:EOF
[2010-01-03 23:09:51 - DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts: 1
```

a quick Google didn't reveal anything particular useful.  What are the next debugging steps and/or what might be the issue?

UPDATE: So this actually isn't a problem like I thought it was, but I'd still be curious what this message means if anyone knows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

DDMS uses a long-lived connection to the `adb` server running locally to get info about connected devices/emulators etc.  The error message you posted generally just means that the connection to `adb` has been lost.

Because you ran the reset command, you essentially just killed and restarted an `adb` process, so Eclipse showed that harmless warning for a moment.

You can see this yourself by killing the `adb` process manually.  Eclipse will show `Connection attempts: n` for about 10 attempts before giving up.