# Why doesn't logcat show anything in my Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, logcat

Why doesn't [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) show anything in my Android (while developing apps with Eclipse)?

It just doesn't print anything. It's empty.

Comment: Is it the logcat View in Eclipse that's blank, the output of the `adb logcat` command, or both?

Comment: It may also happen when debugging Android 7 (or higher) devices.
[See this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351106/eclipse-empty-logcat-with-android-7)

Comment: What do you mean by *"in my Android"*? Do you mean *"on my Android device"*? Or *"in Android Studio"*? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2250112/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maybe you have [Mylyn](https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) installed?

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1808

Comment: That doesn't matter.  I removed my Mylyn plugins, and the issue persisted.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to down-vote this answer, it's the accepted answer because it solved the problem for TIMEX. If this is not your issue then feel free to up-vote another answer.

Comment: What is "Mylyn"? Can you add a link (or similar) to your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I had trouble remembering what it was myself ;)

Answer (score 521):

I had this same issue but my fix was much more basic:

If the LogCat panel is empty in Eclipse the emulator doesn't have the focus. Go to the DDMS perspective and try clicking on the 'emulator' entry in the Devices panel (top-left screen).

Comment: Same thing happens with a physical device. You just have to click on the entry representing that device and the log messages suddenly come flooding in.

Comment: If this doesn't work right away, restart eclipse, then it works, thanks @MoMo

Comment: On my target device, it showed my activity, click on it and then click on **Start Tracking** on the next window.

Comment: from last month I restart the eclipse as solution, you make it more faster :)

Comment: I have no idea where the "device tab" is supposed to be - someone has a picture?

Comment: **Window** / **Show View** / **Other...** / **Devices**. I've just upvoted this answer to 500.  ;-)

Comment: @Tyler 12 years later and I have the same problem but this time clicking on the entry representing that (physical) device does not solve the issue. OTOH, every now and then I see all LogCat messages in one single long line. Could the problem be my el-cheapo Redmi 6A phone?

Answer (score 83):

Dial

```
*#*#2846579#*#*
```

and you will see a hidden menu. Go to the Project Menu > Background Setting > Log setting and define the log availability (log switch) and level (log level setting).

**Please note this may apply to Huawei phones only** as is stated for an Ideos X3 ([here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17774443&postcount=8)) and is tested at a Honor U8860.

Comment: To tell the truth, my Honor starts showing log in LogCat and then it may stop. I don't rely on LogCat with *this* device. You may install CatLog (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) or a similar tool - that one always works! Good luck.

Comment: Make sure you restart your phone after setting the log.

Comment: Works on Huawei P7-L07

Comment: Worked for Huawei P8 Lite - ALE L21 ! Thank you !

Comment: Worked for Huawei MediaPad M2 8.0 M2-801L Tablet.

Comment: There isn't any hidden many. It showing "VersionInfoQuery" activity. And also in that UI only provide information about version, Device ext..
Need help

Comment: this solution did worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691076/logcat-not-showing-errors-from-my-huawei-p9-phone

Answer (score 71):

If clicking in Devices panel doesn't bring the spam, use `reset adb` in dropout menu from triangle on the right of the snapshot button.

Comment: Watch out because Console will spit out [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF... Connection attempts: 1. As posted elsewhere on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997474/android-eclipse-plugin-reset-adb-gives-adb-connection-erroreof-error-not-b), this is benign but you will have to unplug/reconnect your devices so they show up.

Comment: This fixed it, and I didn't have to reconnect my device for it to show up, fwiw

Comment: Just found it, but I only get message that Adb connection was forcebly close and no reconnection.

Answer (score 41):

I have the same problem on/off and the way I solved is by menu *File* → *Restart* (restart Eclipse).

Comment: No need restart eclipse > just select your emulator or device from DDMS

Comment: We dont have time to restart the eclipse as it takes 5-10 minutes :(

Answer (score 11):

While [the answer provided by MoMo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android/2945333#2945333) will resolve the problem temporarily it will most likely reoccur the next time you launch Eclipse, or launch on a different Emulator/Device.

Instead of always having to select my device in the devices view I've found a better solution is to go into your Eclipse preferences and navigate to Android -> LogCat in the list on the left and then enable "Monitor logcat for messages from applications in workspace".

This way no matter what device you are using logcat will automatically start showing output from it as soon as the application launches.

It will also setup a filter that ensures that only output from your application is displayed, which you can reuse / disable as needed.

[image: Logcat application output enabling setting]

Comment: "Window" -> Android  -> ... etc.

Comment: INFO: This fixed LogCat on Blackberry Priv Android 5.1.1 Only when I press RUN and this is enough

Answer (score 10):

Maybe the log is not enabled in your device.
Try to run the following command.

```
adb shell
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/logger/log_main/enable
```

Comment: That was the problem in my Huawei U8500. Neither adb logcat nor eclipse were showing anything. Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean if there is no 'logger' directory inside of `/sys/kernel`?

Comment: Try in another directory: 
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/logger_mode/logger_mode

Comment: That directory is not there either. There is a config directory, but it is empty.

Comment: @Roland There is no `/sys/kernel/logger` in Redmi 6A (the device I use for debugging).

Answer (score 6):

OK. This is how I got it to work. I first followed [MoMo's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android/2945333#2945333), that is...

> If the LogCat panel is empty in Eclipse the emulator doesn't have the
> focus. Go to the DDMS perspective and try clicking on the 'emulator'
> entry in the Devices panel (top-left screen).

**But to no avail.**

I then attempted to `reset adb` (Android Debug Bridge) as [suggested by fyodorananiev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android/9115238#9115238).
How? Menu *Window* → *Devices* → upside down triangle menu button → *Reset adb*.

It also **didn't work**, but I did get the following message:

> Android hierarchyviewer: Unable to get the focused window from device

This meant that MoMo was right in that my Android device or emulator didn't have focus. However, the solution I did in my case is different.

**What worked for me:**

1. Replugged my Android device, which was connected to my computer via USB.
2. Restarted Eclipse, as mentioned by Abu Hamzah (although since I didn't know I can do menu *File* → *Restart*, I manually closed down Eclipse, and then restarted the application again.)

I can now see logs in my logcat.

Comment: What worked for you is waaaay too cumbersome and time consuming. It used to work for me without a hitch on a Nexsus One and LG LS670 and Samsung Galaxy S. I have no idea what happened the current state of Eclipse+ADT development (other than that it is no longer supported by Google).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a device, the simplest check is to restart Eclipse.

**You don't have to shutdown Eclipse**

Use menu *File* → *Restart*

In a quick second or two you should see your LogCat return.

Comment: it is as long as shutdown eclipse, I don't see the difference.

Comment: @LeSam, yeah, the only difference is that Eclipse is re-started automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Developer settings and check that for Debugging\Select App for Debugging is empty

[image]

Comment: I have a BLU Dash XL. I couldn't see the log and tried this solution. BAM! Worked!! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, `Select debug app` does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution worked for me: Shutdown and restart my phone and Eclipse alike.

Comment: No need restart eclipse > just select your emulator or device from DDMS

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't selected the device or emulator, on which running your application.

In Eclipse, go to **DDMS Perspective** and select the device or emulator on which you are running your application.

**(Note: No need to restart Eclipse)**

Answer (score 2):

It gets interesting when you find out that *none of all the answers* in for this question were helpful.

And then you find out that in your version of ADT **22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206** if you add two filters with the same package name (*application name*) then the log will not appear.

It was weird, because the log was there two seconds ago, and launching the app in debug mode adds a default filter for the app which collides with the filter I've setup manually, and then ADT magically removes all the logs, and **none** of the filter worked including the **all messages (no filters)**!

But it was masking another issue...

I'm working with dual screens. The second one is connected via VGA/RGB - (not really sure what it's called) and what can I do. I'm a ton more comfortable with the logcat away from my code editors, so I've placed it in another window, and as it turns out that is the main reason for the disappearing logs for me.

Answer (score 2):

In case if you are using [CyanogenMod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod) in your mobile, it will disable logging by default. Try this method:

In your device, open "/system/etc/init.d/" folder
If there are many files, try opening each file and find for this line:

**rm /dev/log/main**

Now, comment this line like this: **# rm /dev/log/main**

Save the file and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same issue but in my case logs are shown when other devices are connected and not shown when my device is connected.

It took me days and finally, the issue resolved when I restarted my phone.

Comment: Happened to me too

Answer (score 2):

**Below: Really dumb answer, but it happens!**

My cat stepped on the space button while I was away and [SPACE]xN was typed in the search bar.

That resulted in an empty Log Cat. I tried restarting and wasted like 1 hour before I realized I should clear my search bar.

***TLDR; CLEAR YOUR LOG CAT SEARCH BAR!***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If using the DDMS to refocus doesn't work, try closing and restarting LogCat. That helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen occasionally.  Closing and re-opening Eclipse seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried all of the others, and still got losing on an *empty* logcat. I got another simple way.

Download an old version of ADB, and try again. It might be working, at least working for me with Android 7.0 phone (vendor stopped updating).

[Here](http://www.downloads.puresoft.ir/files/android/platform-tools/) is the useful link for old versions.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Console is telling you something. Usually this happens when the project could not be installed in the device, and just shows the previous one.

The most common case I have seen this is when there are different signatures in the project, and is not running at all.
Please, read all the red letters you see. If the LogCat does not show anything, take for sure that the Console will do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. No need to restart Eclipse or clean your project. You may follow:

1. Click on LogCat icon on bottom right corner of eclipse.
2. In Saved Filter Pane (Left side), double click package of your project (in my case it's com.apps.***.****).
3. In Logcate Message Filter Settings popup, select desired option of "by Log Level". You can select verbose, info, error etc.
4. Click Ok.
5. Run/Debug your project.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me besides restarting Eclipse was:

- Remove custom filters

After removing all filters, logcat was filled with text again

Answer (score 0):

Close logcat and then reopen it from *Window* → *Show View* → *Others*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Eclipse v4.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Mars) (at least, Mars.1 or Mars.2), try the solution described here: *[Logcat show invisible messages in Eclipse Mars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403672/logcat-show-invisible-messages-in-eclipse-mars)*.

It helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple.

Just close the Logcat from eclipse.

Then reopen it by following steps in Eclipse.

**Window - Show View - Other - Android - LogCat - ok**

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set the *same* date and time in your Android phone and in your laptop.

I had a similar problem of logs not showing, and when I set the correct date in the phone I started seeing the logs (I restarted the phone and the hour was completely wrong!).

Answer (score 0):

Many times when I switched to a new Android device, I do see no more logcat messages. Unfortunately, none of the above suggestions worked for me (Eclipse Photon 4.8.0).

I am now using [this](https://bitbucket.org/mlopatkin/android-log-viewer) . It seems to work for different devices.

Answer (score 0):

For [OnePlus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnePlus) devices and Ubuntu OS:

- Install [Wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) on Ubuntu
- Install ADB tools on Ubuntu

  ```
   sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
  ```
- Now, attach your device to PC with USB.
- Open mounted "One Plus Drivers". A disc like icon
- Right click on OnePlus_USB_Drivers_setup.exe and run with Wine
- Then open the terminal in the present drive where your "OnePlus_USB_Drivers_setup.exe" and other driver files exists. And run

  ```
   ./adb_config_Linux_OSX.sh or sh adb_config_Linux_OSX.sh
  ```
- Close this terminal
- Open a new terminal and run

  ```
   adb server-start
  ```

Your OnePlus device should prompt you to recognise your PC as a debugging agent.

Now, run on the terminal. It should show your device.

```
adb devices
```

Reference: *[[SOLVED] Android Studio does not recognise my One Plus Two in Linux](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/solved-android-studio-does-not-recognise-my-one-plus-two-in-linux.365221/#post-13208160)*

Answer (score 0):

In my case (after trying all the answers provided here to no avail), the problem (and solution) has to do with port 8700:

[image]

What I needed to do is:

1. Exit "Android Device Monitor" (monitor.bat)
2. Exit all instances of Eclipse.
3. `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools>..\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server`
4. `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools>..\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server`
5. `C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools> monitor.bat`

Also, the Scroll Lock button, needs to be "pressed/active":

[image: logcat scrolling]

Not the other way:

[image: logcat paused]

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps that helped me

1. Verify the variant you are working on and check app has debuggable true in gradle. It may be possible you are some other variant and have check for `BuildConfig.Debug`

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            }
}
```

2. Try selecting the device properly if you are working on `Android studio`
3. Try closing and reopening the logcat; sometimes I found this is the only issue
4. Try restarting the adb

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```