# Why does Android DDMS show logs for a few hours, but then fail?

Tags: android, ddms

I use IntelliJ IDEA to write Android apps, and use the DDMS Windows application to view the Android logs (separate from the IDE). It works fine, but after a seemingly random period of time, the logs vanish, except for one line of log, which gets overwritten with incoming logs. I have to shut it down and restart it, which combined with the delays of deploying an app to a device over ADB to debug and test is pretty tiresome.

Is this a known issue with DDMS? Is there anything I can do to make it work consistently without breaking itself?

Are there any other Android log viewing applications for Windows that work better? I'm not very fond of the IntelliJ IDEA one. My favourite is actually CatLog on Android itself, but on a small-screen device it's not a great experience.

Comment: I've found that pressing the `clear log` button also temporarily fixes the issue without having to restart ddms.

Comment: Yes, me too, though it seems random whether it fixes it or not. My thery is that DDMS has a buffer that fills up, and once full it fails, as it seems since my current app had more logging added, DDMS fails more often.

Comment: there are a few suggestions in [this thread](http://www.anddev.org/sdk-adt-emulator-problems-f16/logcat-overflow-t5955.html), I've not tried any though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the time, but number of lines being recorded. As Dave C said in the comment, just clear the log and it will be fine

Comment: Clearing the log doesn't fix it. I clear it regularly, but it still fails. How can I extend the size of the log buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at ["Why doesn't LogCat show anything in my Android?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android)? The top voted answer may solve your problem

Comment: 'Fraid not. The problem isn't that I get no log output, but that after a while it stops scrolling down the screen, all appearing on one line. Clicking on the device in DDMS doesn't often fix it, the solution is a tedious restart