# Load new page on button click in android?

Tags: java, android, button

I am making a game in android. I want to make a main menu screen that has two buttons, one to start the game and one to display the how to screen.

I have classes for both, but when I launch my name and test the buttons, the application crashes. Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
       public void launch()
       {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.testing.blockinvasion", "com.testing.blockinvasion.game");
            startActivity(i);
       }

       public void howto()
       {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.testing.blockinvasion", "com.testing.blockinvasion.howto");
            startActivity(i);
       }

}
```

My buttons are defined in my main.xml:

```
 <Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/Start"
     android:onClick="launch" />
```

EDIT: I ended up just deleting the project and starting another one and everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: Waqas is correct. If you specify the listener functions using the `android:onClick` attribute then the functions must accept a `View` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct your method signatures. So do it in this way:

```
public void launch(View v)
```

and

```
public void howto(View v)
```

Comment: does it still Force Close? if not, then now its a different issue... post your logs for that

Comment: My logs say that the function launch for example is not found

Comment: you must be doing something else wrong. paste your entire code

Comment: clean your project and build again. besides paste your logs from logcat

Comment: Cleaning and re-build didn't change anything

Comment: its strange. your code seems fine to me. comment everything inside your button methods and just print a log message to check if the button action is working

Comment: How do I print a log message?

Comment: Log.i("btnLaunch", "launch button is clicked");

Comment: I can't see the log. Where specifically should I look. I cannot see it in the Console or in LogCat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android

Comment: I dont understand what that link is asking of me

Comment: I'm getting a "nosuchmethod" exception

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

private OnClickListener button1Listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent howto = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), .class);
            startActivity(howto);
        }
    };

Assigning a different OnClickListener object to every button --> button1.setOnClickListener(button1Listener)

Anyway, are all the Activities defined in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Initially, I had not defined my activities, but now I have and it still does not load (it prompts me to force close the application)