# How to open a new page by tapping a button?

Tags: android

I'm a noob to programming, and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to create another page and be able to tap a button on the main page to access the new page.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144500/load-new-page-on-button-click-in-android

Answer (score 2):

well for this you need the knowledge of [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in Android coupled with the knowledge of [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) which are used for inter-activity communication. After that you will have to learn the [Gestures](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html) and their [implementations](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html) in Android.

Please note: This was probably your first question. that's why you wont understand negative votes that you are getting. Read the about page of Stack Overflow and understand what the site is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Just set Onclicklistener for your button. on Onclick(), use Intent to move to your next   activity.Activity, here means view,according to you.

Answer (score 0):

And for Xamarin if you want it

[Xamarin Intent](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/intent/)

Like this

```
menu.Click += delegate
        {
            var intent459 = new Intent(this, typeof(MenuTopActivity));
            StartActivity(intent459);
        };
```