# Android 4.0 --- no logcat messages from Log.i function in an Android program

Tags: android, logcat

My new Android 4.0 device seems could not output Logcat messages.

I have an Android program that runs OK on an Android 2.2 device and could output `Log.i` messages in the Eclipse ADT Logcat window. However, when I run this same program in my new Android 4.0 device, I could only see messages with `dalvikvm` and `OSFileSystem` tag in the Eclipse ADT Logcat window, the `Log.i` messages from the program are missing.

I have followed this thread [Why doesn't logcat show anything in my Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android) and tried to change the file `/sys/kernel/logger/log_main/enable` in my Android 4.0 device. But I find that my Android 4.0 device has only the directory up to `/sys/kernel`. The files under `/sys/kernel` are :

```
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-05-03 13:17 uevent_seqnum
-rw-r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-05-03 13:17 uevent_helper
-rw-r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-05-03 13:17 profiling
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2012-05-03 13:17 ipv4
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2012-05-03 13:17 mm
```

I think the rom settings in my new Android 4.0 device may have blocked the `Log.i` messages from my program. Does anyone know how to turn on the `Log.i` messages for my device.

My Android 4.0 device is not rooted.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Have you set `android:debuggable="true"` in the AndroidManifest's application tag?

Comment: Do you see output from other files? Maybe you have your logcat filtered? Try running `adb logcat` from command prompt and see the logcat there (to exclude eclipse as a point of failure)

Comment: After adding, the "application" element in "AndroidManifest.xml" becomes : `<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">`, but there is still no "Log.i" messages from program.

Comment: I have tried `adb logcat`. There are many outputs in the terminal. But there is no "Log.i" messages from the program.

Comment: Could you try to increase the log level by using `Log.e` instead?

Comment: If you are working with a real device, you will have to enable USB debugging on your phone/tablet as well.

Comment: Yes, I check that I have already enabled USB debugging in my Android 4.0 phone.

Comment: I have replaced all "Log.i" with "Log.e". But the problem remains the same.

Comment: your device is connected and the only one running? No emulator running on the pc? If so I have no clue whats going on...

Comment: Yes, the 4.0 device is the only one connected to the PC with no emulator opened. My program runs OK on the 4.0 device, just no Logcat outputs from the "Log.x" statements. It may be due to the specific settings in my Android 4.0 device. My "ASK SP404" is not a branded smartphone. I just share the problem here hoping that someone has a solution for this 4.0 phone.