# Android Development LogCat

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm trying to debug my application on my Huawai Acend G330. But I can not figure out how to use LogCat the Application starts but all that logcat is saying: 
"info: log device is empty!"

even if i type "adb logcat" in the console this info is shown. Under DDMS I seleced my device and adb also found it.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: This link should be able to help: [Why doesn't Logcat show anything?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android)

Comment: When i use the emulator i get the logcat messages. only the real device does not work. also with the samsung galaxy s3 it just works fine :-/

Comment: Have you enabled development/debug settings in the phone's system settings? Maybe there's an extra switch for the log? There are slight differences how this is implemented from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

This solution WILL work, since it worked for me, and I have the g330, too.

Dial **`*#*#2846579#*#*`** in the phone to open a secret menu, choose "ProjectMenu", then "Background setting" and finally "Log setting". In there, "Log switch" lets you activate\deactivate the log, and "Log level setting" lets you choose which entries you will see in the log, exactly like you can do in logcat's settings in eclipse.
After activating the log, restart the phone and you will be able to see it in eclipse exactly the same way you see the emulator's log.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please definitely look at all the options in this Most Excellent link:

- [Why doesn't logcat show anything in my Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android)

2) Nick is right - there might be something odd about this particular handset that you need to configure and/or install.

3) Here is a link dedicated to debugging for the G300:

- http://www.modaco.com/topic/359891-how-to-install-adb-and-logcat-for-g300/

4) Finally, check out this link (from the above "logcat-for-g300" link):

> - http://goo.gl/3lhwy
>
> /proc/last_kmsg (not available in G300 CM9.  Possibly in the future?)