# Creating a simple output to logcat

Tags: android, logging, int

I can't figure out the proper way to output an int the logcat and the [api document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) doesn't make sense to me.

I feel like this should do it:

```
package com.example.conflip;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        flip();
    }

    public int flip() {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int outcome = randomNumber.nextInt(2);
        Log.d(outcome);
        return outcome;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

However I only get the error `The method d(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Do I need to cast the int to a string? And if so, how?

**Update:**

Though all the solutions below do work, LogCat would not display output until I selected my hardware device in DDMS.

Answer (score 2):

use `Integer.toString(outcome)` as you need String as parameter in Log

```
so overall Log.d(tag_name, Integer.toString(outcome));
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) you can see details of Log.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line before onCreate method

```
private static final String TAG = "your activity name";
```

and now you in flip

```
Log.d(TAG, "outcome = " + outcome);
```

Comment: I can't get around this error `Illegal modifier for parameter TAG; only final is permitted`. An explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the problem is a spelling error because I get the same error.

Comment: TAG should be declare as a class member. If it is local take out private.

Comment: You do not call flip() anywhere in your code. maybe you mean to put flip() after setContentView

Comment: You're right. But also it turns out I didn't have a device selected for logging. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android

Answer (score 1):

Use Log.d(String, String).  The first string is a tag that will appear in the logcat-  an easy identifier you can search for.  The second is the message printed to log.  To get the string for an int, use Integer.toString(value).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public int flip() {
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    int outcome = randomNumber.nextInt(2);
   Log.d("This is the output", outcome.toString());
    return outcome;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String TAG = "MainActivity"; //-------------Include this-----------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        flip();   //----You miss this out perhaps-----
    }
public int flip() {
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    int outcome = randomNumber.nextInt(2);
    Log.d(TAG, "Checking Outcome Value:" +outcome); //----Include this--------
    return outcome;
}
```

You can also change Log.d into Log.i  (Information) , Log.w (Warning), Log.e (Error)

That depends on what type of message you want to display (Mainly different in color).

Comment: As @Hoan Nguyen said, You did not initialize `flip();` in your onCreate. Therefore, it did not go through the Log.d process. Check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

you should use   string.valueof(integer) to get the output in log cat for eg.

```
int outcome = randomNumber.nextInt(2);
        Log.d("urtag",String.valueOf(outcome));
```