# samsung s3 logcat messages

Tags: android, logcat

In my Samsung S3 phone application specific logcat messages are not coming. I have installed aLogcat application. Logcat messages like "SensorManager : Set normal delay = true" kind of messages are coming in the logcat application.

But in my app I have following statements in button click event.

```
            Log.i("start", "testing");
            Log.d("Log.d", "Log.d");
            Log.e("Log.e", "Log.e");
```

These messages are not coming in the logcat application in the S3 device. But the same messages are coming in the eclipse emulator.

Comment: see if this link helps. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2250112/2021499

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aLogCat application has an issue since JELLY BEAN android version.... Its manifest doesnt declare READ_LOGS permission...

To use it, you can download Terminal Emulator or simply use ADB, then input:

```
pm grant org.jtb.alogcat android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

And reboot your phone or force close & reopen aLogCat

Source:

```
http://zerocredibility.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/286/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I tried the above command in adb shell I got the error "Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.GRANT_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS."

Comment: Do this : `adb shell`, then `su`, then posted command... That way you will have superuser rights to do that.

Comment: I dont have root permission in the device. Is that the problem? When I tried su, it also gives an error like 'su' not found...

Comment: It seems that not being rooted is the cause... You could try rooting your device,  although there should be a way to do that without rooting it.  I cant investigate it, because i am not at home now :)

Comment: Try this command directly. Lets see if it works `adb shell pm grant org.jtb.alogcat android.permission.READ_LOGS`

Comment: If that didnt work, you will havecto root your device, dont worry its easy :) First install a custom recovery and the flash this .zip `http://download.chainfire.eu/315/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.25.zip`

Comment: pm grant org.jtb.alogcat android.permission.READ_LOGS worked in my Google Nexus phone. It have root access. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a shell/terminal emulator? I use ROM ToolBox's inbuilt command prompt and launch logcat from there by using the command "adb logcat"