# How to get rid of HUAWEI_DEBUG logs?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I have a Huawei U8950 phone and use it for Android Development. The problem is that the guys at Huawei has left their debug logs on and my logcat output is always flooded with hundreds of log messages like this:

```
E/OpenGLRenderer(10525): HUAWEI_DEBUG: glyph's Height = 21, Width = 13, current total allocated size out of MAX(1024) = 17 
E/OpenGLRenderer(10525): HUAWEI_DEBUG: glyph's Height = 21, Width = 15, current total allocated size out of MAX(1024) = 16 
E/OpenGLRenderer(10525): HUAWEI_DEBUG: glyph's Height = 21, Width = 15, current total allocated size out of MAX(1024) = 32 
E/OpenGLRenderer(10525): HUAWEI_DEBUG: glyph's Height = 16, Width = 13, current total allocated size out of MAX(1024) = 16
...
```

These message are so so many (hundreds or even thousands) and make Eclipse hang (I think because of parsing and coloring) that I don't use it anymore and use `adb logcat` manually. However in there too I have to deal with them and see and scroll them.

Is there any way to disable them? (Software solutions for filtering them is not good, because the overhead of transferring and processing still remains)

Comment: Filtering them at the command line with grep should not be much overhead.  You probably cannot disable them at the source without installing a new Android build.

Comment: Yes you are right. `grep`ing is not a bad idea at the end. I asked that way because I though maybe Huawei has though of this and there would be an option hidden somewhere on the device to disable them. Because Huawei had initially disabled logcat and put a hidden menu to enable it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10963065/1385489)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install busybox you could do

```
logcat | busybox grep -v HUAWEI_DEBUG
```

in adb shell or ssh. Some builds have busybox ,but you will probably need to install it. Thankfully there are tons of apps that drag it along - most terminals do.

Comment: There's no need to install busybox, simply run grep on the development machine rather than on the device.  Additionally, recent Android releases now provide a grep.

Comment: True, but don't know of a way to do that on a windows machine.

Comment: There are many versions of grep available for windows.  There's also nothing in the question to suggest the development machine runs windows though of course that is a possibility (it is not generally a preferred platform for this work, so found mostly where people are coming from something else)

Comment: Thanks guys. I use Ubuntu for development. This helped for the manual using of `adb logcat`. Is there any way to solve the eclipse problem too? I mean place this filter automatically somewhere so that eclipse would get filtered logs?