# Eclipse LogCat not working

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

Somehow my LogCat is never working any longer. After the app has launched, it reports absolutely **nothing** no matter what happens (exceptions or whatever - nothing is reported after launch)

I had some problems with my Eclipse installation in the past, but it is now otherwise fully working, so I am wondiering if it may be a simple "debug" setting somewhere?

Comment: are you able to see your emulator/device in the devices tab of DDMS perspective?

Comment: @SMR yes, my device is running. I can also step through code. But if e.g. an excpetion happens and the app crashes, LogCat has nothing at all (ever)

Comment: @RajithaSiriwardena My LogCat reports up till the point the app is launched

Comment: Actually, even if not the same problem description, I did actually find my answer there. (Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer here:
[Why doesn't logcat show anything in my Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android)

> Dial
>
> *#*#2846579#*#*
>
> and you will see a hidden menu. Go ProjectMenu / Background Setting /
>   Log setting and define the log availability (log swith) and level (log
>   level setting).
>
> Please note this may apply to Huawei phones only a

by https://stackoverflow.com/users/874502/denispyr

And it seems to have solved the problem