# Logcat not showing errors from my Huawei P9 phone

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I am using Android Studio 2.3 and my phone is Huawei P9 Lite. I noticed that my logcat does not show errors from my phone. For example if I have code that will crash because of `NullPointerException` and I run it on emulator I get exception in logcat (font color: red) and popup saying `MyApplication stopped working`, but if I run same that code on my phone, i just get crash popup and nothing in logcat. Info messages are displayed, but errors are not. What do I need to do in order to show error messages from my phone in logcat?

Comment: Clear filters, set option "no filters", and check log level

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Huawei, logcat not showing the log for my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124334/huawei-logcat-not-showing-the-log-for-my-app)

Comment: @Yazan Thank you, I have solved the problem

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Huawei disables LogCat and any access to the logs of your phone. You should go to a hidden menu where you can enable these functions.

1. Open your Dialer app and enter the following code: *#*#2846579#*#*.
2. Enter the **Background Settings** page.
3. Click on “**Log Settings**”
4. Check all **3 options to enable** full logging.
5. **Ignore** the "will affect performance" warning.
6. **Reboot the phone**.

This helped me, hope it will help to you, too.

[image]

Source: https://www.xda-developers.com/huawei-phones-disable-logcat-heres-how-to-restore-access/

Comment: Yes, I did this back then and it worked as @Yazan mentioned in the comments of this question.

Comment: Perfect solution for me - except (for me) **don't reboot the phone**.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I solved it as below:

[image: Select Tools -> Android -> then disable ADB integration and then re-enable it. Hope it'll help you]

Select Tools -> Android -> then disable ADB integration and then re-enable it. Hope it'll help you

Answer (score -1):

Don't close this popup as this will clear your logcat.

if nothing has appeared try the *emphasized text*

First, make sure you have chosen your mobile from here 
[image]

and set the filter to verbose:
[image]

Comment: I have selected my phone, and I have set log level to verbose, and no filters

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use debug .
2. You can use Log :

int ASSERT
Priority constant for the println method.

int DEBUG
Priority constant for the println method; use Log.d.

int ERROR
Priority constant for the println method; use Log.e.

int INFO
Priority constant for the println method; use Log.i.

int VERBOSE
Priority constant for the println method; use Log.v.

int WARN
Priority constant for the println method; use Log.w.

Example : 
if i want to log to error log so i will use 
Log.e("TAG","Message");
its will print in error log "Message"
and you can fillter it by the tag "Tag"

Comment: `Log.e()` is shown, but some code where I do not need `try-catch` for example if `NullPointerException` occurs application crashes and I do not see error in logcat from phone, however I see it if same code runs on emulator