# android studio logcat does not show the reason of crashes when i run my app on a real phone

Tags: android, crash, logcat

I have a strange problem. when I run my app on Genymotion with android 4.1, everything is good and Logcat works fine and shows everything. but when I run the same app on a real phone(Huawei honour 7 with Android 6), and my app gets crash, logCat does not show the reason for that crash. in the other word, log cat does not show Exceptions. can anyonehelp me?thanks

maybe be useful:

logCat After a crash:
[image: Photo]

**build.gradle(module app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ....
}
```

Comment: did you get exception while launching?

Comment: Did you select your own device in logcat console ?

Comment: @Joe yes. i did

Comment: Some times android Studio can't detect the android phone, you can install driver of that phone to your system.

Comment: @ThomasMary yes. I've selected.

Comment: How do you installing your app to the phone .??By android studio debug or another source @Hadi

Comment: @Abhishekkumar but when i myself print a log by Log.i, logCat shows that log. but does not show Exceptions like NullPointException, fileNotFoundException, sslException , etc

Comment: @Abhishekkumar by android studio

Comment: Is your phone showing on logcat ? @Hadi

Comment: @Abhishekkumar yes. it is shown.

Comment: At right side of the logcat select Show only Selected application.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar I have tried that but the result was the same.

Comment: Check on regex and select error , if not then close android studio and again open.

Comment: If it will work for you please reply. @Hadi

Comment: @Abhishekkumar I have tried all. but not worked.

Comment: can you attach the logcat screensort to the question @Hadi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164557/discussion-between-abhishek-kumar-and-hadi).

Comment: @Abhishekkumar ...

Answer (score 9):

Best way to fix this to invalidate caches, may it will worked for you.

Go to **FILE** -> click "**INVALIDATE CACHES/RESTART**" then a dialog box will pop-up, Select "INVALIDATE CACHES/RESTART" button.

Android studio will automatically restart and rebuild the index.

**or,**

You can do the following things.

1. Restart logcat
2. Change from verbose to debug/error.
3. The last (Checked the regex ) Change the regex to show selected options only.

or, Look into this [Logcat not showing errors from my Huawei P9 phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691076/logcat-not-showing-errors-from-my-huawei-p9-phone/43557441)

Comment: i tried all but now workd. the post edited. I've attached a screen of logcat after a crash.

Comment: i tried all but not worked. the post edited. I've attached a screen of logcat after a crash.

Comment: thanks my friend. my problem solved with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691076/logcat-not-showing-errors-from-my-huawei-p9-phone/43557441. thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome, @Hadi , on my first comment i already told its phone issue BTW, Happy Coding..