# Logcat doesn't show errors only

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, samsung-mobile

Logcat specifically doesn't show errors for my real device Samsung S8, but it does work fine for all other devices, so for now whenever I have an error and I can't see it in the log, I need to switch to another device and reproduce it again.

Did anyone face something like this before? any help appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: I've experienced it before on a Samsung tablet.

Comment: @JojoNarte had a solution for it?

Comment: No solution yet

Comment: This worked for me on my Huawei device https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691076/logcat-not-showing-errors-from-my-huawei-p9-phone/43557441

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see any error in log-cat.

please don't run your project use "Debug" mode 
[image]

& see your log-cat into your debug section. [image]

If this not work read this [Android studio logcat nothing to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432358/android-studio-logcat-nothing-to-show). it might help you

Answer (score 0):

This Helped Me.
To be sure that you select the right device:

[image]

After that check it
[image]