# How to see crash report in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash-reports

I think Android Studio is broken, I don't get any crash report. Yesterday I spent 1 hour to figure out that I forgot to call `findViewById(R.id.MY_ID);` by debugging I need to see the crash report.

I work on physical device.

Comment: Check your filtering option in logcat, maybe you are filtering it? Maybe you are on warning or something and it's in error

Comment: still don't get it

Comment: are you using device? or emulator??

Comment: @Sadegh device do you have solution

Comment: in some devices LogCat is disable and you must find hidden menu in your device and enable that. like in huawei this solution can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691076/logcat-not-showing-errors-from-my-huawei-p9-phone  you can search about your device model

Comment: omg thank u very much i didnt know that there r something like this i really appreciate this and my phone is huawie and i fount the hidden menu thank u very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search google for
**how to open YOUR_PHONE_BRAND hidden menu**
open it open
then open Background Settings then Log Settings then Check all 3 options to enable full logging Reboot the phone
for Huawei [Logcat not showing errors from my Huawei P9 phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691076/logcat-not-showing-errors-from-my-huawei-p9-phone)

Answer (score 0):

this is from a couple years ago but a similar situation (and solution) is described here:
https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-fix-android-studio-3-1-error-debugging-issue-8d06ad9f49a9

Comment: cant reach this page

Answer (score 0):

You can see the crash report at the bottom of the run tab.