# Logcat not displaying Application logs

Tags: android, logcat

So, it is not that the Logcat is not displaying logs at all - it displays some system logs but none of my App logs are visible. I have tested the App instance by connecting to multiple devices and that is the only device it is happening with. The device has Android 7.0. In other devices, I am able to see the App logs.

I have tried invalidate caches -> Restart option but to no avail.

Is there any other troubleshooting I can perform here?

Device: https://www.amazon.in/Micromax-C1A-Blue-2GB-16GB/dp/B07RD6J6RH

Comment: Can you check if you're using some filters which might be causing this? Like using a different or a different log level than verbose or some regex?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't logcat show anything in my Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250112/why-doesnt-logcat-show-anything-in-my-android)